# Why did the Apostles say to obey God rather than men?

Tags: biblical-basis, bible-translation

As per scripture Act 5: 29-30

> 29 Peter and the other apostles answered and said, "We ought to obey God rather than men. 30 The God of our fathers raised up Jesus, whom ye slew and hanged on a tree."

Comment: The question is unclear, are you asking what the context is, or what are you asking?

Comment: Peter the apostles of Jesus Christ too saying to obey GOD.

Comment: I don't understand, who should they have said to obey? What does this mean for you? What is the confusion? Jesus also said to obey God. Please state clearly: "The apostles said to obey God instead of men, I interpret this as meaning X and am confused because of Y."

Comment: Playing English semantics with the terms birth, et al, is an unproductive line of inquiry.

Answer (score 2):

The Acts passage is about contrasting and authorizing what God said, the "it is written", versus what tradition or elders or authorities might say in opposition.

Though not written per se at the time, Christ had told them to spread the Good News.  Subsequently it was written.

> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit, 
>   Mat 28:19

The authorities to the contrary were telling them to stay quiet.

> “We [Sanhedrin] gave you strict orders not to teach in this name,” he said. “Yet you have filled Jerusalem with your teaching and are determined to make us responsible for this man’s blood.” But Peter and the other apostles replied, “We must obey God rather than men.
>   Acts 5:28-29

For the apostles, they chose to obey God, rather than men.  It was clear to Peter and the others that God had foretold through prophets that Christ would come, die, and be resurrected.  Indeed, they knew this was fulfilled and what they were to do with it.

About 100 years later, [Polycrates of Ephesus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycrates_of_Ephesus) would be forced to also make a decision between what he knew was apostolic versus what [Victor of Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Victor_I) was saying and teaching.

> 7. I [Polycrates], therefore, brethren, who have lived sixty-five years in the Lord, and have met with the brethren throughout the world, and have gone through every Holy Scripture, am not affrighted by terrifying words [from Victor]. For those greater than I have said ‘We ought to obey God rather than man.’
>      [-source-](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf201.iii.x.xxv.html)

The apostles and others subequently made a choice to obey God, rather than men.

Comment: A minor point that the Apostles were not obeying 'what is written', they were obeying what Jesus had told them, which they took as authoritative from God. But it had not been written down at that time.

Comment: Tried to clarify the point (via voice at first versus it is writtne later), though the point would remain--"it is written" versus traditions and opinions of men, elders, authorities handed down verbally.

Comment: The only traditions condemned in Scripture are those which are set against, and which make null, the Word of God. Not tradition in general. Scripture is a tradition. The canon is a tradition. —Reading itself is a tradition.

Comment: @SolaGratia  True enough. That was the point of the apostles saying as they did and then Polycrates saying as he did. The trick, if you will, is to know the difference between God's word (scripture) and traditions (of men). They, the two examples, did, as indicated, via "it is written". As Polycrates said, I have gone through every Holy Scripture, which for him, if you can believe it, included, along with the OT, the NT as we know it.  For Polycrates, Victor, like the Sanhedrin some 100 years before, was teaching traditions. For Peter, apostles, and Polycrates, they prefered God's instruction.

Comment: You agree and then go on to define anything not written in Scripture as "of men."

Comment: I'm guessing you are arguing for something called "official tradition" (or Tradition) as on par and equal with somehow scripture.  As you said and as I agreed when tradition or "official tradition established by one's denomination" is set against or contradicts or embellishes or adds to or subtracts from scripture, I'm fairly sure we'd reject that Tradition, as did Peter, the apostles, and Polycrates.  Perhaps you could frame a new question on this issue?

Comment: Of course we'd reject a tradition we thought contradicted Scripture; but the method, 'sola scriptura' couldn't be used to determine whether it contradicts, since it is exclusive of tradition. If we really wanted to test whether a tradition contradicted Scripture, we would need already to accept that not only Scripture is informative of doctrine, otherwise we would infallibly find all not in Scripture to be embellishment or taking away therefrom.

Comment: If both inform doctrine and Scripture and Tradition are the true rules of Christian doctrine, it might not be that they are at odds, but that we are reading contrary to the apostolic sense Scriptures which are in fact in agreement with the tradition passed on along with them, or a part which rather they in fact are themselves.

Comment: @SolaGratia it sounds to me like you don't understand either the question or the answer, but rather are arguing a point that doesn't exist within the context of said said and answer.  Again, I would suggest, rather than wasting more time and expending more energy, for you to frame a new question with your concerns that have nothing to do with this question and answer.

Comment: You were question begging too hard for me not to respond but we must end this here, I agree.